# Does Thomae's Function has functional limit for all points in R?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know that Thomae's function is continuous at all irrational numbers, so there are functional limits for those point. However, I don't know about rational numbers...

Thank you!

Comment: Here read this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function It talks all about it.

Comment: Thanks! However, I only see that talks about continuity but not functional limit?

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is a rational number, and $f$ is Thomae's function, then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$, but $f(a) \ne 0$. Thus Thomae's function has a limit at every real number, but is continuous exactly at the irrational numbers.

The fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$ for all $a$ is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197788/proving-thomaes-function-is-nowhere-differentiable); the proof is essentially identical to the irrational case, which is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/641431/68107).