# Prove that f(x) is regulated.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Define $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x):=0$ if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$, $f(p/q):=1/q$, $q>0$, $p, q$ coprime integers.

Prove that $f$ is regulated.

> A function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is a regulated function if $\forall \varepsilon>0$ there is a step function $\varphi:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ such that $sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-\varphi(x)| <\varepsilon$.

So far I've worked out that $f$ is continuous at all irrational values of $x$ and discontinuous at all rational values of $x$ but I'm unsure what to do next.

Edit: I've also worked out that because $f=0$ or $f=1/q$ and $0<1/q\leqslant 1$ then $0\leqslant f \leqslant 1$. I'm not sure if this helps?

Comment: If we allow the indicator function of singleton as step function, proving this problem is easy. But if we does not allow it as step function, then I think $f$ is not regulated.

Comment: If I'm being stupid please excuse me, but what is the indicator function of singleton?

Comment: I intend a characteristic function of set only has one element. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) may helpful for you.

Comment: The indicator function $\psi_{\{a\}}$ of the singleton (i.e. set with a single element) $\{a\}$ is given by $$\psi_{\{a\}}(x) =\cases{1&if $x=a$ (actually if $x\in \{a\}$)\\0&otherwise} $$

Comment: What set would I use for $a$ though? The obvious choice is for it to be either the rationals or irrationals but in either case $\psi_{a}(x)$ wouldn't be a step function so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is regulated if and only if it has RHS limit at $x\in[a,b)$ and LHS limit at $(a,b]$.

Hint: ($\impliedby$) $\forall \epsilon>0$, Let $A=\{x\in [a,b]\,|\exists \, \text{step function}\, s: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}\,\text{such that}\, |f(z)-s(z)| <\epsilon, \forall z\in[a,x]\}$.

Try to show $A=[a,b]$.

Thomae's function has limit $0$ at all real number ( which is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698448/does-thomaes-function-has-functional-limit-for-all-points-in-r)), so it's regulated.

But here I also allow step function of degenerate interval.

Comment: How would I prove that it has limit $0$ at all real numbers though? Is it because there is infinitely many irrationals on the interval $[0,1]$ so there's infinitely many points where $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @john.smith The proof is quite similar to show it's continuous at irrational number. I have updated a link in my answer.